# SeaweedFS How to set readTimeout argument?

Tags: seaweedfs

I have read through the seaweedfs wiki and found that there is an argument that could be helpful in my case of handling large files over unpredictable network connections this argument is `-readTimeout=` as described in the wiki optimization page under upload large files section, could anyone please guide through how and where can i use this argument.

Comment: What have you tried so far, with a code example? Remember: StackOverflow is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Answer (score 1):

use "-idleTimeout" option